# Which uniformed search algorithm is the best here?

Tags: algorithms, searching

So I have an exercise like this where I have to choose the best strategy. I wonder here which one is the best:

> A robotic engineer wants to add movement planning ability to a small
>   mobile robot. The planner software must find a sequence of basic move
>   and turn actions that will get the robot from its initial position to
>   a goal position, avoiding certain obstacles with known locations. To
>   generate such movement plans she has decided to implement an
>   uninformed search algorithm but is unsure whether to use breadth first
>   search, depth first search or iterative deepening.

I would choose iterative deepening with the explanation that it's complete if b is finite and optimal if all the step costs are identical, which are the cases in this case, while BFS will take lots of time and space and DFS the same.

Would I be right?